# Getting the roles from the HttpContextBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, role

There is a way to get the array of role from the HttpContextBase ?

I'm looking to do a class like that:

```
    public static IList<string> GetUserRoles(this HttpContextBase context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {

        }

        // return roles array;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()
```

For what reason do you want to use  HttpContextBase?

*** EDIT ***
Oops, I see now you want the list of roles for a given user.
I thought you wanted the list of all available roles.

you could loop through the roles and check which ones apply:

```
HttpContextBase.User.IsInRole(role);
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're using a GenericPrincipal in the Application_AuthenticateRequest. I would suggest you to create a custom principal which exposes an array of roles:

```
public class CustomPrincipal: IPrincipal
{
    public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity, string[] roles)
    {
        this.Identity = identity;
        this.Roles = roles;
    }

    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string[] Roles
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return (Array.BinarySearch(this.Roles, role) >= 0 ? true : false);  
    }
}
```

now you can read your cookie and create a custom principal.

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[My.Application.FORMS_COOKIE_NAME];
        if ((authCookie != null) && (authCookie.Value != null))
        {
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "FormAuthentication");
            var principal = new CustomPrincipal(identity, Roles, Code);
            Context.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

and your function would look something like this:

```
    public static IList<string> GetUserRoles(this HttpContextBase context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            return(((CustomPrincipal)context.User).Roles);
        }

        return (null);
        // return roles array;
    }
```